# Check a specified users group membership

Tags: sql, sql-server, active-directory

Is there a way to check a specified users active directory group membership via T-SQL?  I am looking for a method similar to IS_MEMBER but one that accepts a username and group as  parameters

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914698/query-ad-group-membership-recursively-through-sql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query AD Group Membership Recursively Through SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914698/query-ad-group-membership-recursively-through-sql)