# SQL Server 2014 - ADP Query pulling partial members

Tags: sql-server, active-directory, sql-server-2014

I am using the query below to connect to AD from a SQL Server 2014. The user id used for linked server ADSI is an admin and  has full rights.

This query returns only 7 members but in fact there are 21 members. Powershell returns 21 members (can't use it for different reasons)

```
SELECT 
    sAMAccountName as Login, 
    CN as Name, 
    GivenName as FirstName,
    SN as LastName, 
    DisplayName as FullName 
FROM 
    OPENQUERY(ADSI, 'SELECT
                         sAMAccountname,
                         givenname,
                         sn,
                         displayname,
                         CN 
                     FROM
                         ''LDAP://DOMAIN/DC=...,DC=...'' 
                     WHERE 
                         objectCategory = ''person'' 
                         AND objectClass = ''user''  
                         AND memberOf = ''CN=group1_Users,OU=Groups,DC=...,DC=...'' 
                     ORDER BY CN')
```

I am not sure at this point what could be wrong. I looked all over and it seems there is no solution.

I only want to pass that one particular group name.

However, doing the opposite, meaning looking for a user ID, getting the ADSPATH and passing it to get the groups that the user is a member of works.

This is working for me but I don't need it.

[Query AD Group Membership Recursively Through SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914698/query-ad-group-membership-recursively-through-sql/)

I also tried this but I still get 7 members

```
DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'CN=group1_Users,OU=Groups,DC=...,DC=...',

SET @Query = 'SELECT cn, AdsPath, samAccountName
              FROM OPENQUERY (ADSI, ''<LDAP://domain/DC=...,DC=...>;(& 
                                      (objectClass=User)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=' + @Path +
                                     '));samAccountName,cn, adspath;subtree'')'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @Query
```

Comment: Can you show us the PowerShell command you used that gave you 21 members?

Comment: This turned out to be a "Setting". On the ADSI linked server, you must specify the domain name even if you are admin and you specify just username/password it wont work. it must be DOMAIN\Username .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a setting on the SQL linked server properties. 
if you use "be made using the login's current security context" and you are a domain admin it will not work . 
you have to specify "Be made using this security context" **AND** specify the DOMAIN name in the user such as DOMAIN\Username.  It did not work without the DOMAIN name.